# Are there any Live CD versions of Ubuntu any more?

Tags: boot, live-cd, cd

Is there a CD version that lets you boot without changing anything on the HD's? Everything I find is to big to fit a 700MB CD.

I have an old server that crashed and it only has a CD ROM. I've tried using the USB ports but no luck.

Comment: There's the Ubuntu mini.iso (net install), around 40 MBs.

Comment: The current answers ignored the first line of this question. This is about Live CDs, not just any image that'll fit on a slice of toast. I have edited the title to clarify this point.

Comment: Simply put, I don't think Ubuntu fits on a CD anymore. At least, not a live session like you're looking for.

Comment: "without changing anything on the HD" - you could put the full size iso on the HD and [boot it from grub](http://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/) using Grub's isofile loopback support if that counts?

Answer (score 5):

[Lubuntu has an iso that is under 700mb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO).  I'm not sure if it has liveCD capabilities though.

PuppyLinux is a distribution designed for this kind of purpose.  One of the most recent community releases ([Tahrpup](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/tahrpup)) uses the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS packages.

Comment: The Ubuntu server CD is not a live CD. It's installation only.

Answer (score 2):

### Answering the question

Since you ask on AskUbuntu, here's an answer to what you're asking for.

#### "boot without changing anything on the HD"

The regular (not the alternate or server) ISOs of major flavors of Ubuntu, whether 32-bit or 64-bit, can **all boot live** on a machine to test drive without installing.

I personally booted Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu from live USB (and in older years, CD) to get a graphical desktop and run some tools, even sometimes on machine without storage.

#### "fit a 700MB CD"

Most of these ISO are bigger that 700MB.  But some Lubuntu ISO are smaller

This link: [Lubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/?C=S;O=A) shows the current Lubuntu ISO **sorted by size**.

You can see that nearly all desktop ISOs of the first release (i386, amd64+mac, amd64) are smaller than 700MB (683MB to 694MB). Only the powerpc variant is over 700MB.

Updated  tend to be bigger.  So, if 700MB is a hard limit for you, use an ISO of the first release.

### Other solutions considering your need: "old server that crashed"

That said, since you mention rescuing an old server:

- If for your rescue task you can **figure out the tools you need, find them use them on your own**, then a **live Ubuntu** (or derivative system) is handy (or any environment you're already familiar with for that matter).  This has the benefit that once booted on the machine, even if a needed tool is not on the ISO, one can use `apt-get` or `aptitude` to **get tools from the Internet**... assuming the machine can access the Internet.  I actually happen to often keep in my work bag some USB sticks with Xubuntu and they saved the day sometimes.
- In other cases, e.g. **not savvy enough, not sure about the work to be done, cannot access the Internet**), it might make sense to use a **dedicated rescue live distribution**.  Being dedicated to a smaller subset of tasks, they can (1) often guide the user, e.g. with a menu (console-based or graphical) to a list of (2) highly relevant tools that wouldn't be included in a generic live system, or (3) tools to fix problems on other widespread operating systems.  Also, (4) not running a full desktop may make sense the old target machine doesn't have much RAM (**more RAM will be available** as e.g. disk cache to boost performance instead of being dedicated to eye candy).

Distrowatch offers a filtering interface that may help find what is best for you.  Here's an example: [Linux + Data Rescue + Under 700MB distributions according to Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=Linux&category=Data+Rescue&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&package=All&rolling=All&isosize=Under+700MB&netinstall=All&status=Active) offers 6 options, including the well-known SystemRescueCD

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use a convenient tool called [**Plop Boot Manager**](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/index.html). It’s a small [bootloader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting) that provides a menu to select the device you want to boot from. If your BIOS doesn’t support booting from USB devices but still detects the devices at boot, this should be all you need.

[image: Plop screenshot]

<sup>(Taken from the [screenshots](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/screenshots.html) page)</sup>

This is Plop’s interface – you just hit the down key to highlight USB and press enter. On some computers I’ve noticed USB devices are displayed as hard drives, so if that doesn’t work be sure to try drives other than the boot drive (typically the first one).

The download contains an ISO image that any CD burning tool will accept. It's only a few megabytes in size.

Comment: This would precisely answer the question if the OP mentioned that it's just a matter of booting the server (it might actually be the case but why would they write "without changing anything on the HD" since booting a full system actually changes things). Anyway, some rescue disks also have an option to boot on first hard disk. Also, Plop Boot Manager is very light. It can be installed on a floppy disk and be used to boot from an USB device on a computer so old that its BIOS can't boot from USB but has a disk drive.

Answer (score 0):

You might check with OSDisc.com. I don't know how many MB their live/install cd's have, but you could email them and ask. They usually run $5.95 to $19.95 and will refund your money.  I'm using a live/install Ubuntu on an old Dell Inspiron laptop to get familiar with the os and it works fine, but it was not purchased from OSDisc.com. Hope this helps.